# Pandas most efficient store NUMERIC(8,3) in dtype?

Tags: pandas, postgresql, numpy, types, precision

Pandas/numpy come with [a variety](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) of dtypes for numerical values.

For memory and computing reasons, I try to be as explicity as possible.

[Coming from the postgres world](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html), I try to bring `NUMERIC(8,3)` to a suitable `dtype`.

Easy said, `NUMERC(8,3)` can represent all numbers with five digits before and 3 digits after the dot (IT guy in math..). *Max* would be `9999.99`, min `0`.

Are there more precise data types in pandas/numpy to define this as in postgresql? In which kind of `dtype` such a value should be stored?

```
df['my_numeric'] = df['my_numeric'].as_type('???')
```

**EDIT** after two answers:

I am more looking into *spending* less space. E.g. `df.memory_usage()` on a 374k rows dataframe, shows 3mb on a `float64`, 1.5mb on a `float32`, 750kb on a 16-bit and 375kb on a 8-bit column.

So if I got it right, I need 13 bit for the main number and 7 bit for the precision. `float 64` [has](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) *11 bits exponent, 52 bits mantissa* and is able to store all values. But it also takes way more memory than it would really needed.

Comment: you can try: df['my_numeric']  = pd.to_numeric(df['my_numeric'], downcast='float')

Comment: Thanks @GustavoGradvohl. Which range than can be assumed and how much bits will be reserved on each value?

Comment: On modern computers the default `float64` is suitable for most numeric work.  The processors are designed to work with this size of number. That's the `double` mentioned here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT.  `numpy/pandas` does not handle `arbitrary precision` (`mpmath` is needed for that).

Comment: It depends if you doencast from float64 to float 32 wil cut the size in half. Some colums can be cast as category and could have significant savings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need `clip` ?

```
s
0    100000.000000
1         0.123457
dtype: float64
s.round(2).clip(lower=0.01,upper=9999.99)
0    9999.99
1       0.12
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Kind of @YOBEN_S, this helps to speed up some computations. But the memory allocation will be still the same (64bit). I updated the question based on your answer, thanks.